# What does the abelianization mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, torsion-groups

Abelianise each of:

(a) $\Bbb Q \times S_4$

(b) $D_{12} \times A_4$

(c) $G \times Z_{10}$, where $G$ is the dicyclic group of order 12

and write down the torsion coefficients of the resulting abelian groups.

So I'm working on this question from Mark Armstrong's *Groups and Symmetry*, and I feel like I'm missing something. I know that "abelianization" is the process of making a non-abelian group abelian, and the way to do that is to find the commutator group and use it to divide the original group to get a quotient group that is abelian. I'm not sure how to go about this is a practical sense, though - to find the torsion coefficients, I needs groups of integers or something that is isomorphic to groups of integers, but I'm unsure of how to go from $\Bbb Q \times S_4$ to the quotient group I need

Comment: Two useful facts: If $G$ and $H$ are groups then $(G \times H)’ =G’ \times H’.$ Also, if $A \lhd G$ and $B \lhd H$ then $A \times B \lhd G \times H,$ and $(G \times H)/(A \times B) \cong (G/A) \times (H/B).$

Comment: "universal for the homomorphisms to abelian groups" $G^{ab}\times H^{ab}$ is abelian so it must be a quotient of $(G\times H)^{ab}$, and $[G\times H,G\times H]$ contains $[G,G]\times [H,H]$ so $G^{ab}\times H^{ab}=(G\times H)^{ab}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, find the commutators and then mod out.

For the first one, $\Bbb Q$ is commutative.  And it is well-known that the commutator of $S_n$ is $A_n$.  So we get $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Z_2$.  And the torsion coefficient is $2$.

For the second, the commutators of the factors are $\langle r^2\rangle= D_{12}'$ and the klein four group $V= A_4'$.  It is well known that the abelianization of $D_{2n}$ is the klein four group $V$.  So, we get $V\times\Bbb Z_6$, and the torsion coefficients are $2,2$ and $6$.

Finally, the abelianization of the dicyclic group $G$ is known to be $C_4$, the commutator being $C_3$.  We thus get $C_4\times\Bbb C_{10}\cong C_2\times C_{20}$, with torsion coefficients $2,20$.

Comment: I think if the torsion coefficients are written in increasing order then each one should divide the next one, which means that in the last example they should be $2,20$ because $C_4 \times C_{10} \cong C_2 \times C_{20}$.